# How do I figure how much time it takes for some line to be executed in Java?

Tags: java, performance, low-level

Suppose I have some code, and I want to optimize it to the maximum, disregarding readability, maintainability, etc.

For this purpose, is there anyway to figure out how much time every basic action takes? I suppose this may be CPU dependent, but I'm not sure.

I mean stuff like cycling through a `for`, assignments `a=24`, mathematical operations `2+25`, etc.

Comment: Then how do I know how much time `System.nanoTime()` takes? Surely this will add quite a bit.

Comment: He means between two instruction using the current time in nano seconds you could get the execution time.

Comment: @BenoitVanalderweireldt Well, suppose I do `System.nanoTime(); 2+25; System.nanoTime();` then, if nanoTime took 0s to complete, I could know the time taken to perform `2+25`, but this carries the time taken to perform `System.nanoTime()` aswell.

Comment: Use a [**profiler**](https://www.google.com/search?q=java+profiler).

Comment: If every time measurement you make is artificially increased by the time taken to execute `System.nanoTime()`, does it really matter? You can still compare two operations and determine which took longer, which I assume is your intention.

Comment: @SimonMᶜKenzie Yes, you're right, I realized that a bit after I made that comment. Although I was looking for a more computer-science theoretical answer, something I could translate from pc to pc without doing so many tests.

Comment: You can't. That "line of code" is translated into bytecode, which could be executed several different ways during a single launch of a program.

Comment: I would argue that tests performed on a given PC are only relevant on that PC, so since you can't compare results between machines, it still doesn't matter, as your time measurement method (whatever you use) will (hopefully) always take the same time to execute.

Comment: Benchmarking is hard. And the granularity you look for even harder. Besides measuring javacode with good frameworks like JMH you can also use Java or OS profilers. Some are even integrated into JMH.http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/architect-benchmarking-2266277.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Context matters.  There aren't fixed costs for various Java language constructs that you can just add up to get even an approximation of a useful run-time estimate.  **The answer you seem to be hoping for doesn't exist.**

Even if you did manage to correctly design a microbenchmark to measure some `if()s` vs. a `switch`, for example, the results would be heavily dependent on the surrounding code, the details of what the cases were, and the predictability of the branch.  Making microbenchmarks is *hard*.  You often end up measuring something other than what you intend to, unless you look at the machine instructions that actually run in your loop.  It's also easy for a good compiler to optimize away your loop if you don't use the results, but then it's hard to use the results in a way that doesn't create more overhead than what you're trying to measure.

A good JIT-compiler JVM should generate machine code that's not too much worse than what you'd hope for, so if you have a good sense of how C compiles to ASM, that could be useful for java.

If you want to learn what is fast vs. slow on modern x86 microarchitectures, have a look at [Agner Fog's guides](http://agner.org/optimize/).

A good profiling tool can help you figure out whether your code is CPU-bound or bottlenecked on memory (cache misses: memory bandwidth or latency), or branch mispredicts.  I haven't done this for Java, but the standard tools (like Linux's `perf`) probably work as long as you use a long enough run to hide the overhead of the JVM startup.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like:

```
long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
// ---- Your code ----
long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis()
System.out.println("The previous line took " + (endTime - startTime) + " ms");
```

Comment: Won't both calls: `System.out.println; System.currentTimeInMillis` add a fair bit of time between the completion of the previous lines  and the output?

Comment: If you want to be more accurate you could use more fine-grained time measure like `nanoTime`.